# Laravel eloquent collection query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a search endpoint for one of my pages but i am having a little trouble writing the query for it to get it going

**Team Model**

```
public function members()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Membership', 'team_id', 'id', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

**Member(user) Model **

```
public function skills()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Skill')->withPivot('boosted');
}
```

if i access the collection via `$team->members;` it returns the correct team members

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1507 ▼
 #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => App\User {#1508 ▶}
    1 => App\User {#1509 ▶}
  ]
```

}

i have attempted below within my search function but when i dump the query it basically just returns all the team's and every member belonging to them when it should only be returning 2 members that belong to one specific team like the eloquent collection above.

```
    public function search(Team $team, Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->get('search');
        
        $members = Team::with('members')->whereHas('members', function ($q) use ($search) {
            $q->where('id', 'like', "%$search%");
        })->whereHas('members.skills', function ($q) use ($search) {
            $q->where('name', 'like', "%$search%");
        })->paginate(10);

        return view('team.show', compact('team', 'members'));
    }
```

Are you able to do `where()` directly on the collection like this?

```
    $members = $team->members;
    
    $memberQuery = $members->where('name', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('id', 'like', "%$search%");
```

the idea is to go through the member relation within the team model then add the abilty to search through specific fields and do a `WhereHas` on the skills relation within the member(user model) so i can also search for a field within that too.

I am a little lost on the solution to my problem can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you can do `$team->members()->where(....)->get()`

Comment: okay ill try this, what if i want to join the skills relation after i've done the where() on the members field?

Comment: so either you `leftJoin()` by hand or you use `with()`

Comment: So your $search should check for the `id` of the members as well as the `name` of the skill?

Comment: yeah so it should be able to search for the `id` and `name` of members and the `name` of skill

Comment: Okay, is there an OR condition between those two or and AND condition?

Comment: ive also tried this but had no luck its just returning a bunch of users -   $members = $team->members()->with('skills')
            ->where('id', 'like', "%$search%")
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', "%$search%")
            ->whereHas('skills', function ($q) use ($search) {
                $q->where('name', 'like', "%$search%");
            })->get();

Comment: @Aashishgaba yeah so you should be able to search for id OR name of member OR name of skill

Comment: @Lowtiercoder, I've added an answer, give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218972/discussion-between-aashish-gaba-and-lowtiercoder).

Answer (score 1):

```
$members = Team::whereHas('members', function ($q) use ($search) {
             $q->where('id', 'like', "%$search%")
               ->orWhere(function($q) use($search){
                  $q->whereHas('skills', function($q) use($search){
                      $q->where('name', 'like', "%$search%"); 
                  });
              });
        })
        ->with([
           'members' => function ($q) use ($search) {
             $q->where('id', 'like', "%$search%")
               ->orWhere(function($q) use($search){
                  $q->whereHas('skills', function($q) use($search){
                      $q->where('name', 'like', "%$search%"); 
                  });
               })
           },
           'memebers.skills' => function($q) use($search){
                $q->where('name', 'like', "%$search%"); 
            }
        ])
        ->paginate(10);
```

**whereHas** plays the main role, as it will get only those teams who have members, whose `id` is like `$search` or their skills have `name` like `$search`.

And as we only need to get the members which satisfy the condition, it is being handled in the **eager loading**(we're eager loading only those particular members whose `id` is like `$search` or their skills have `name` like `$search`.)

You can refer to this blog. It has explained this kind of approach in detail
https://medium.com/@sander3/laravel-nested-eager-loading-contraints-9742c2dac4b9